# Creating an angularjs app from existing javascript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've built a simple taxation calculator that I want to integrate into a angularjs application. I've had a look at angularjs and can't quite get my head around how to integrate existing js code. Can someone suggest a simple way of (re) architect it into an angularjs app?

Thanks

```
//constructor to create the initial object. Accepts object and creates new taxCalculation object
function taxCalculation(configuration){
      this.superAnnuationPercentage = configuration.superAnnuationPercentage;
      this.superAnnuationTaxRate    = configuration.superAnnuationTaxRate;
};

//creating a new object "tax" with taxCalculation constructor

var tax = new taxCalculation({
    superAnnuationPercentage: 9.25,
    superAnnuationTaxRate:  15
});

//Defines HECS/HELP repayment brackets
var hecs = [
{from:0,     percentage:0},
{from:53346, percentage:4},
{from:59422, percentage:4.5},
{from:65498, percentage:5.0},
{from:68940, percentage:5.5},
{from:74106, percentage:6.0},
{from:80258, percentage:6.5},
{from:84482, percentage:7.0},
{from:92971, percentage:7.5}, 
{from:99070, percentage:8.0},
];

//Defines the tax brackets
var taxBracket = [
    {from: 0, percentage: 0, baseAmount: 0},
    {from: 18201, percentage: 19, over: 18200, baseAmount: 0},
    {from: 37001, percentage: 32.5, over: 37000, baseAmount: 3752},
    {from: 80001, percentage: 37, over: 80000, baseAmount: 17547},
    {from: 180001, percentage: 45, over: 180000, baseAmount: 54547}
];

//Calculate the super annuation component of grossIncome
taxCalculation.prototype.grossSuperAnnuation = function(income){
    return income * this.superAnnuationPercentage / 100;

};



//Calculates tax on super annuation component
taxCalculation.prototype.superAnnuationTax = function(grossSuper){
  return grossSuper * this.superAnnuationTaxRate / 100;
};


//Calculate gross income
taxCalculation.prototype.grossIncome = function(grossIncome){
    return grossIncome - this.grossSuperAnnuation(grossIncome);

};


//Calculates HECS bracket based on gross income
taxCalculation.prototype.hecsCalculation = function (income){
        for (var x = 0; x < hecs.length; x++){
            if(income >= hecs[x].from){
            var percentage = hecs[x].percentage/100;
            }
        };        
        return income * percentage;
};


//Loops through taxBracket object and finds the tax bracket for the post deduction gross income amount
taxCalculation.prototype.taxBracketCalculation = function (grossSuperIncome){
    for(var x = 0; x < taxBracket.length; x++){
        if(grossSuperIncome <= taxBracket[x].from){
            var amountOver = grossSuperIncome - taxBracket[x].over;
            var percent = taxBracket[x].percentage / 100;
            return taxBracket[x].baseAmount + (amountOver * percent);
        }

    };
};

//Calculate all of the factors in tax calculation
taxCalculation.prototype.totalTax = function (income){
  var taxResult = {
    income: income
  };
  taxResult.superAnnuation = this.grossSuperAnnuation(income);
  taxResult.grossIncome = this.grossIncome(income);
  taxResult.taxBase = this.taxBracketCalculation(taxResult.grossIncome);
  taxResult.taxSuper = this.superAnnuationTax(taxResult.superAnnuation);
  taxResult.hecs = this.hecsCalculation(income);

  return taxResult;
};

var test = tax.totalTax(65000);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: I'd put the whole thing into a single service.

Comment: yes this is more like a service and does not depend on any UI.
You could be using Angular, Ember, Backbone, whatever framework it'll be the same, you're not storing anything neither showing anything (except in the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already explained by Shomz and Huafu, you should put your code into a angularjs service.

Create an service that contains all your code. But I think you might have to change names of the functions. As example only a subset of your code:

```
app.service('taxService', function () {

function taxCalculation(configuration) {
    this.superAnnuationPercentage = configuration.superAnnuationPercentage;
    this.superAnnuationTaxRate = configuration.superAnnuationTaxRate;
};

//creating a new object "tax" with taxCalculation constructor
var tax = new taxCalculation({
    superAnnuationPercentage: 9.25,
    superAnnuationTaxRate: 15
});


//Calculate the super annuation component of grossIncome
this.grossSuperAnnuation = function (income) {
    return income * tax.superAnnuationPercentage / 100;

};


}
```

Btw, I think there is a typo in your code, `this.superAnnuationPercentage` does not exist outside of the object `tax`.

Then reference the service inside a controller:

```
app.controller('IncomeController',

function IncomeController($scope, taxService) {
    $scope.tax = "undefined"
    $scope.calculate = function () {
        $scope.tax = taxService.grossSuperAnnuation($scope.income);
    }
});
```

Reference the controller and call the `calculate` function from your angularjs page:

```
<div ng-controller="IncomeController">
    <input ng-model="income" />
    <button ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <p>{{tax}}</p>
</div>
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgm3zsL3/)